# SlickGrid Expand-Collapse a group of columns

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I'm using current distribution of SlickGrid from 6pac.

I'm looking for a way to Group Columns so that user can expand / collapse those group of columns to show / hide them. This is similar to Column Grouping available in MS Excel.

Searching for this functionality led me to below plugin
https://github.com/naresh-n/slickgrid-column-group

This plugin allows grouping of columns but doesn't provide for a way to toggle visibility of those columns.

Has anyone been able to achieve this behavior?

An example of AG Grid with the desired behavior: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping-headers/#example-basic-grouping

Comment: As far as I know, no-one has done this before. It is quite easy to hide and show columns (using setColumns(), see the example), so the visual layout is probably the hardest part to get right.

Comment: Agree @ben-mcintyre; Google didn't help so far ! :)

Comment: and you can also add this as a new plugin to Ben's 6pac repo, we like having new plugins, it's even easier to merge if it doesn't change or affect the core library when the plugin is completely independent.